# VueJs - bind input to url param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, vue-router

I would like to bind an input field to a route param in vue.js.

```
<input v-model="$route.params.query"/>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 22):

The most straight-forward way I found was the following:

```
<input v-model="foo" />
```

--

```
data() {
    return {
        foo: this.$route.query.foo
    };
},
watch: {
    foo(newVal) {
        this.$router.push({ query: { ...this.$route.query, foo: newVal } });
    },
    '$route.query.foo': function(val) {
        this.foo = val;
    }
}
```

Edit 2019-08-16: added watch for `$route` to react to back navigation.

Comment: For me, this.$router.currentRoute.query.foo was required in the data function

Answer (score 12):

A bit of time has passed, but since the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) say *"it is often a better idea to use a computed property rather than an imperative watch callback"* I thought I would add this pattern which I tested successfully and also looks more elegant IMHO.

The idea is to use a `computed` property linked to the query param with explicit `get` and `set` methods and bind the input with `v-model` to that property.

So in your template:

```html
<input v-model="query_param"/>
```

Then in your computed properties:

```js
computed: {
  query_param: {
      get() {
        return this.$route.query.your_query_param
      },
      set(value) {
        /*  Here I use replace so that you're not actually 
        pushing a new page to the history stack */

        this.$router.replace({  
          query: {
            ...this.$route.query,
            your_query_param: value
          }
        })
      }
    }
}
```

This of course would work for a single query parameter. If you have multiple inputs you want to bind to different parameters just put additional computed properties in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. In my code, I have a `<select>` element on change of which I want to append the selected value to url as query. So, I have done like this: 
My previous URL was:

*localhost:8080/books*

```
<select class="form-control" v-on:change="appendQueryToUrl" v-model="filterData.genre">

methods: {
      appendQueryToUrl() {
          this.$router.push({query: {genre: this.filterData.genre}})
      }
}
```

Where genre is my key and this.filterData.genre is my local object value. Now my url looks like: 
 
*localhost:8080/books/?genre=Computer*

Thanks and inform me if any error.

Comment: Your solution is a one-way binding. If we open localhost:8080/books/?genre=Computer in a new browser window, the input won't be the value of the "genre" param.